File parsing using multiple threads in C++
I am tasked to parse a large text file (size >= 100MB) with specific format and extract some pre-determined tokens which will be processed later using APIs. The file is in the following format (illustrative):
=======DB VERSION 2.0=======
$BLOCK$ block1_name
    $TREE$ tree1_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $END_TREE$
    $SUB_BLOCK$ sub1_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $SUB_BLOCK$
$BLOCK_END$
$BLOCK$ block3_name
    $TREE$ tree1_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $END_TREE$
    $TREE$ tree2_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $END_TREE$
    $SUB_BLOCK$ sub1_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $SUB_BLOCK$
$BLOCK_END$
$BLOCK$ block2_name
    $TREE$ tree1_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $END_TREE$
    $TREE$ tree2_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $END_TREE$
    $SUB_BLOCK$ sub1_name
        /** Info dump related to a data structure **/
    $SUB_BLOCK$
$BLOCK_END$

There are multiple blocks of information in the single text file to be parsed. My APIs also depends on the factor that a single block must start and end on a single thread, because of which I can't split the file either.
Currently, I am using getline function, but it is very slow. I also tried to use memory map file using mio but I was not able to preserve the blocks in a single chunk.
Is there any possibility to enhance performance by parsing and processing each block on different threads?
I cannot share my actual code but it is like below:
void parseFile(){
    ifstream file("file.db");
    string line;
    while(getline(file, line)) {
        Utility::cleanString(line); // Removes trailing spaces
        if (line == BLOCK_START){
            openContext(line);
        }
        else if (line == BLOCK_END){
            closeContext(line);
        }
        else if (line == TREE_START){
            processTree(line);
        }
        else if (line == SUB_BLOCK){
            processSubBlock(line);
        }
    }
}


Just adding threads for reading from a normal file is not going to help much since files are not random access. You also need to find a way to be able to split the files into chunks (in memory, e.g a memory mapped file) to be able to have multiple threads being able to access different parsed. Also if you have that much data... use a database

Reading from a file is, effectively, single-threaded. There's just no nice way to read a file from multiple threads simultaneously. Use one single thread to do all the reading and parsing, and use a thread-pool to handle the processing of each block.

No, multiple threads won't help you improve performance, I foresee. As with any performance improvements, you need to measure progress. In general, your question here seems pretty vague, in particular that "a single block must be parsed by only one single thread" doesn't make much sense without further context.

@UlrichEckhardt edited the requirement, it is that the start and end of a block must exist in a single file only.

Please show a [mre] of the code that you're using, exact performance measurements and the desired performance. Are you using compiler optimisations?

@AlanBirtles I have added an example, the opening and closing of context of the API is based on the start and end of block.

Have you measured that getline is causing the performance issue rather than the rest of your code? Are you using compiler optimisations?

Even your filename suggest that you really want a databases ;) Is there a reason you absolutely must use a text file? And have you profiled your code yet to determine the real bottleneck of your code?

Start by benchmarking a simple while(getline(file, line)) {}. Then tune the input buffer size to number of calls to the kernel.

How often do you need to read this file? Is it only once, at program startup? Once every few hours? Once every few minutes? Once every few seconds? If, for example, you only read the file once at startup, and the program will run for several hours, then is there really a need to optimize? Perhaps if you can change it from a few minutes to under a minute, then it might be worth it. But if you only save a few seconds, you put in more work than it's really worth.

@Someprogrammerdude is it feasible to parse the file on a single thread and simultaneously  process those tokens using API on multiple threads

What I would personally do (perhaps) is to use one thread to read the file, only read. When it gets a $BLOCK$ line, it reads until the $BLOCK_END$, putting every line into a vector. Then it passes on the vector to the thread-pool which distributes it to a suitable processing thread. The processing thread then does the actual parsing of the input, creating the needed data-structures, which it then processes. So the reading thread (which could be the main thread) is rather simple, and leaves all the complexity of parsing and processing to the threads in the pool.

XML parsers can do hundreds of megabytes per second on a single thread; Naive code should get within 10x of that. Throwing more threads at this will be significantly harder than just optimizing your code.]

Also, what is "slow"? I have a json file that's a little over 17MB for me right now (not pretty printed, so it's crammed with data), and it takes about 0.5 seconds to parse and build the in-memory tree. So yeah, it would get more noticeable if it were >100MB (like, let's say 5 seconds for 170MB maybe). What kind of numbers are you looking at for your code?

For example this code in release mode in VS 2022 on my machine reads a 6 million line, 100MB text file in 0.5 seconds, even in debug mode it runs in 6.5 seconds which is still nearly a million lines per second which doesn't seem slow to me

Turns out the parsing is not to be blamed, the creation of objects of classes while processing the parsed tokens are the culprit.

Always profile/benchmark code before even thinking about making it faster
